# What sites should have hyperlinking (onebox) support in chat?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, chat, onebox

Some sites are [integrated to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57286/what-links-and-sites-are-handled-specially-in-chat) . What additional sites should the chat support?

One suggestion per answer.

Comment: I personally think any site with OpenGraph data (complete) and/or an appropriate API should be oneboxed. [see related post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178824/support-for-oneboxing-opengraph-data-in-the-chats)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an extremely old question asked back when oneboxing support had just been introduced. Much like with announcements with feedback answers asked a long time ago, new requests are better made as new questions rather than as answers here.

Answer (score 47):

[GitHub](http://github.com/) project URIs could show a summary of the project. It has [an API](http://developer.github.com/) which could be used to retrieve the necessary data.

[image: Mockup]

[Google Code](http://code.google.com/), [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) and [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/) would also be nice, but I don't think they have APIs that can be used to get project information.

Comment: All for this one!

Comment: And one for this all!

Comment: This would be nice to have.

Comment: it's only missing the number of stars and forks :-)

Answer (score 35):

[RFCs](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2324.txt). Text like `RFC2616` or `RFC-2616` is changed a link that point to relevant RFC page. The Rfc title should also appear in resulting message.

For example:

> [RFC-2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html): Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1

Comment: If we support RFC Hyperlinking, we should link to http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2328 (assuming RFC-2328 is what we were looking for)

Answer (score 24):

Google searches, like http://www.google.com/search?q=waffles could display the top 3 results inline.

Comment: +1 for taking LMGTFY to the next level :)

Comment: Heh yeah there is that to it. Maybe LMGTFY links could also work, and animate inline. That'd be pretty epic.

Comment: How did an [empty wiki](https://www.waffles.fm/Main_Page) get first place?

Comment: @TheLQ this site is priceless: https://www.waffles.fm/Glass_of_Water

Comment: Oneboxing results is a bad idea ... [google?waffles] link hinting would be better

Comment: Teaching people only to look at the first three Google results is a terrible idea. People fail at research enough as it is.

Answer (score 24):

I propose oneboxing support for the [Android Market](https://market.android.com), more specifically for Android apps on the Android Market.

This is the relevant part of an app URL:

```
https://market.android.com/details?id=org.droidstack
```

I guess the most important data is the image, title, author, price and the short description. Additionally there is the rating, version and download count.

Comment: I'll second that.

Comment: absolutely agree

Comment: Definitely, very useful on android.SE

Comment: The iTunes App Store should get equal treatment.

Comment: And Windows Marketplace, given we have http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Disagree for then we shall give equal respect to Apple iTunes marketplace aswell

Comment: @Abhishek If the AppStore would features an API why not? I don't have any problem with the AppStore.

Answer (score 23):

## *DONE*

StackOverflow (and only SO's) blog posts. For example:

> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/new-tag-info-pages/

Useful when talking about recently announced happenings.

Comment: perhaps just wordpress blogs? can this be generalized?

Comment: Awarding this the bounty with the understanding that the Server Fault Blog (proper noun) counts as a Stack Overflow blog (common noun).  Same goes for future official-type blogs.

Comment: What about blogoverflow blogs?

Comment: been implemented @AviD.

Answer (score 18):

http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/

Comment: +1, this would definitely be a good one.

Comment: http://isup.me would also be nice.

Answer (score 18):

probaly difficult, but http://www.wolframalpha.com/ would be cool!

Comment: Very good suggestion, but almost certainly impossible because WolphramAlpha **charges** for the use of it's API, which sucks. Big time.

Answer (score 15):

## *DONE*

Comment links. For example:

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57288#comment-135466

Comment: Usually, comments need context, but being able to preview where you're going is still great.

Comment: This is now done.

Answer (score 15):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Area51 proposal URIs. I've just tested them in the sandbox and they aren't already there.

Comment: Please make this so! I expect them to onebox all the time!

Comment: These have been long available now btw. To be precise, they appeared one day after @C.Ross' comment :)

Answer (score 15):

Tag wiki URIs (not just tags) could display the wiki's excerpt.

Answer (score 15):

Chat is all about communication and this can help users communicate better on the same frequency

- Dictionary web definitions. Kind of like the first result in Google when you type [define:](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=define:supercalifragilisticexpialidocious&pbx=1&oq=define:supercalifragilisticexpialidocious&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=35l35l0l4878l1l1l0l0l0l0l444l444l4-1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=81dcceb860e3dc7d&biw=984&bih=624).
- Urban Dictionary meaning. Useful when you want to explain a street/slang words like [tl;dr](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tl;dr).

This could be useful in the English SE and overall chat in general.

Answer (score 14):

MSDN (if it's not already)

Comment: useless to Food and Cooking, Web Apps, Gaming, Photography, Gadgets.. etc etc

Comment: Perhaps this should be a per-site thing. Is that easy to do?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Most likely not. Looking at how it is designed, it needs to be custom setup for each site that is supported (you can tell because it says "1 votes" on Stack Exchange links). Which would be taxing to try and setup every individual and unique one on every Stack Exchange site.

Comment: For each SE site there will be a set of links that suite that site (MSDN/JavaDocs for SO, Technet/... for SU and SF). So the real answer is that this needs to be extensible enough to allow growth and the set of recognisers (when to apply) and gatherer/transformer (to display) can be customised by chat site.

Comment: @Jeff - so? For Food and Cooking, support epicurious and foodnetwork. For gaming, gamefaq.com. If all sites work for all chats, no problem! There's really no harm done.

Comment: @Jeff: If that was the case, then almost none of the suggestion here except for Google and Wikipedia and other SE sites would work...

Comment: @JeffAtwood. It's useless to them, but so what. It wouldn't hurt them.

Answer (score 14):

[WHOIS database](http://www.whois.net/whois/stackoverflow.com)

Comment: +1 if only for SE beta sites.

Answer (score 14):

Flickr.com / flic.kr (Would be dead handy for the Photo chat room, and there is the handy API already...)

Comment: You can just post a link to the photo...

Comment: @Shog9 The Flickr terms of use say that you can only link to the image if you hyperlink it to the photo's page on the site.

Comment: yes, but chat now provides a tool that will automatically upload the image to imgur and link to that. So, no hotlinking needed. Obviously you should respect the wishes of the copyright owner in cases when the image use is restricted, but that's true regardless.

Comment: @Shog9 Indeed it does; but for the Photo.SE site, most people would already have the images on Flickr

Comment: fair enough, I could see this being more useful for a site like Photo.SE where losing context would be irritating.

Answer (score 12):

[JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)s in Java Development Kit

Answer (score 11):

These are just thoughts, not promises, but possibly:

- lmgtfy (subst for google)
- bit.ly, tinyurl, etc; either replace with expanded link, or at least tell them where they are going
- (process as nested, in case of a lmgtfy behind a bit.ly)

Comment: What about links that do _not_ lead to an http:// scheme? Tinyurl does allow cross-scheme links for those _old_ sites that are still hostile about the variety of schemas used nowadays on the Internet. :P

Comment: @MarcGravell Just a heads up, SE does not care for lmgtfy: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links

Comment: @Nathan - yes, that would be the point. To remove them automatically. I am more than aware of the lmgtfy hate...

Comment: @MarcGravell Ah, that makes sense. I didn't notice you were a moderator before commenting, otherwise I might not have chimed in. ;)

Comment: @Nathan oh it is worse than that; I work here :)

Comment: @MarcGravell I can only imagine...

Answer (score 11):

OData results from SEDE

Answer (score 10):

I propose Google Plus (Google+) accounts and messages.

If Twitter is supported then G+ should be too.

Comment: Indeed! Yet, in contrast to Twitter et al, I’m not sure there’s a G+ API for that. ;)

Comment: Not that this Q&A has been active in ages... But Google+ has now also been dead for ages :P

Answer (score 9):

Other Wikimedia sites (though this may not be as easy as it sounds in my head)

Comment: +1 - particularly Wiktionary.

Comment: See http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Exporting_pages

Comment: wikia sites as well?

Answer (score 8):

[Jargon File](http://catb.org/jargon/html/go01.html) entries.

Answer (score 8):

If you support xkcd there is no reason to exclude userfriendly.org ;-)

Comment: and PennyArcade

Comment: Now Christianity.SE is online, I could see a use for Jesus and Mo. `*ducks flamethrower*`

Comment: And the Oatmeal.

Answer (score 8):

The iTunes App Store, just like the Android suggestion. Actually, all the mobile markets should get one box support.

Answer (score 8):

[Vimeo](http://vimeo.com) (like YouTube) per [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226537/add-onebox-support-for-vimeo)

Answer (score 7):

RSS links. For example:

> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/index.php/feed/

The title, favicon and latest two posts should be fetched.

Comment: The problem is that for every link posted, Stack Exchange must send a HEAD (or GET) request to that server to check if it's an RSS feed or not.

Answer (score 7):

[IACR's ePrint](https://eprint.iacr.org/)

This would be super useful on [Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) and possibly other sites where cryptography gets discussed ([Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/), [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/), and the likes).

For example, one of our users recently [published a tutorial there](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/046). From the link you can extract title, author, abstract, etc and display it in chat.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how [Mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.com) was missed on this list, but as it is part of the larger SE community (albet 1.0), and a fairly successful site, I think it would be nice to have.

Comment: As a StackExchange 1.0 site, Math Overflow doesn't support the Stack Exchange API, so unfortunately this is not possible.

Comment: @balpha lame...

Comment: MathOverflow has now been a 2.0 site for some time, so oneboxing works.

Answer (score 6):

IMDB quotes:

> http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/quotes?qt0424740

```
<div id="qt0424740" class="soda-callout-box quote-callout-box">
 <div class="sodatext">
  <b><a href="/name/nm0000200/">Hudson</a></b>: Let's just bug out and call it even, OK? What are we talking about this for? <br>
  <b><a href="/name/nm0000244/">Ripley</a></b>: I say we take off and nuke the entire site from orbit. It's the only way to be sure. <br>
  <b><a href="/name/nm0000200/">Hudson</a></b>: Fuckin' A... <br>
  <b><a href="/name/nm0001663/">Burke</a></b>: Ho-ho-hold on, hold on one second. This installation has a substantial dollar value attached to it. <br>
  <b><a href="/name/nm0000244/">Ripley</a></b>: They can *bill* me. <br>
 </div>
</div>
```

text gets moved into the box identified by classname `quote-callout-box` and testing indicates that only one gets that designation. You can see the div from that classname and all its raw children above.

Also `$('.sodatext a').attr('href') = 'http://www.imdb.com' + $(each).attr('href');` apparently

I was asked to put something with FHCs so this is for Josh. Or his socks. One of the three I'm sure.
[image: Say hi to the socks Josh!]

Comment: @TheNeedsMoar Aren't they awesome FHCs :D

Comment: Instead of quotes, why not show/movie pages and person pages?

Answer (score 6):

Twitter is supported currently, but Tweets with pictures don't show the image(s) in the one box. Please add support for tweeted images, so you don't have to click the tweet to get to them.

Comment: I really don't understand why Wikipedia images are oneboxed, but Twitter images aren't. Is it because Twitter can have multiple images in the same tweet?

Answer (score 5):

http://www.instantrimshot.com/

Comment: it should play the sound instead of posting a link ;)

Comment: @alex, if only...

Answer (score 4):

[arXiv.org](https://arxiv.org/)

For the back story, I came across a great paper the other day on [Quantum Tokens for Digital Signatures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.09047). I posted a link in [Crypto.SE's chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32682120#32682120). Sadly, it didn't get the first few lines of the abstract, which would have been awesome.

> The fisherman caught a quantum fish. "Fisherman, please let me go", begged the fish, "and I will grant you three wishes". The fisherman agreed. The fish gave the fisherman a quantum computer, three quantum signing tokens and his classical public key. The fish explained: "to sign your three wishes, use the tokenized signature scheme on this quantum computer, then show your valid signature to the king, who owes me a favor".

Answer (score 3):

E-mail addresses. `foobar@example.com` is not currently changed to a mailto: link.

Comment: This would be great... for spammers.  -1

Comment: I would think that any screen scraping software can detect non-linkified email addresses just as well.

Comment: Good point.  I forgot that this would require a non-obfuscated address in the first place.  Downvote removed (sorry 'bout the edit, the vote was too old).

Answer (score 3):

http://www.sadtrombone.com/

(Originally suggested [in the chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/130215) by @badp)

Answer (score 3):

[AlternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net/) has [an API](http://alternativeto.net/api) and could be useful for WebApps and SuperUser.

Answer (score 3):

last.fm so we can share our musics.

Comment: YES PLEASE!!!! For The Tunes room, @balpha!

Answer (score 3):

Since a heaps of these chats are of the intellectual sort, I think oneboxing TED talks will be appreciated.

So how about something like this :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Coding Horror

Coding Horror blog posts should be oneboxed

Answer (score 3):

Try It Online links: https://tio.run/nexus
Useful for showing (partly or completely done) submissions in PPCG, not sure how useful it would be on SO though

Answer (score 2):

Anyway we can onebox Strava profiles/activities? They have an API which you can use located [here](http://strava.github.io/api/)

Answer (score 2):

## CommitStrip

Similarly to XKCD, CommitStrip oneboxing could be added

Answer (score 1):

[O'Reilly Product Page](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596523060/), with the image and short description.

Answer (score 1):

## MDN

For linking relative articles on **Mozilla Developer Network**.

Answer (score -2):

There should be some links about the new version, updates, related to the particular rooms technology. For instance about Android, recently [Lint](http://tools.android.com/recent/lint) is a newly featured added to Android and still many are unware for that, so there should be links about such new update.

Comment: Feeds are already available

Answer (score -4):

Yahoo Answers! But perhaps only to replace the link with a giant troll face.

(Actually I did have [one instance](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1941643#1941643) in which it would have been useful.)

Comment: Not that this Q&A has been active in ages... But Google+ has now also been dead for ages :P

Answer (score -5):

http://www.bbc.co.uk/news

Comment: What about _Le Monde_?  _Der Spiegel_?  _The New York Times_?  _The New York Post_?  _The Weekly World News_?

Comment: @Pops [+1] Might as well wrap all that by simply including news.ycombinator.com ;)

Answer (score -10):

[Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/)

or is this right time to duck for cover ?-)

Comment: I can't imagine a SE site where that would be useful..

Comment: @Blorg - yes, but Twitter - that's another story!

Comment: @Jon, yeah most of the time, but twitter is occasionally the only reference for some recent event, and if the account is verified as someone who should know.. it's useful.

Comment: Eg. Jeff and Joel talk about SE on twitter = useful for meta chat.

Comment: I understand now. Twitter and Facebook are both places where people blurt out meaningless garbage. However, Jeff and Joel blurt out garbage on Twitter, therefore it is useful.

Comment: And just to be clear, my comment just before this proves that MSO is yet another place where people blurt out meaningless garbage :)

Comment: Facebook is evil ... it should be tipped into the fires of mt. doom where it was forged.