# Twitter threading for magic links

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, onebox

Can we have threading for the twitter magic links?

For example: 
[alt text http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/5641/exampletwitter.png](http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/5641/exampletwitter.png)
Should say "Tweeted by ArdaXi on August 8, 2010 at 9:31PM in reply to tzenes", as alexanderpas demonstrates.

Comment: what? I don't understand this request.

Comment: @Jeff - tzenes wants the threading of twitter to show up in the text. When you @ reply to someone, it also shows what tweet you were responding to, like this: http://twitter.com/competentgirl/status/20153209658

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, the twitter magic links don't show the posting method/API/application like the web view does. I don't think it's necessary information, though, in Chat's case

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57288/what-sites-should-have-hyperlinking-support-in-chat