# Can we add support for oneboxing apps from the iOS and Mac App stores?

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What sites should have hyperlinking (onebox) support in chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57288/what-sites-should-have-hyperlinking-onebox-support-in-chat)

I am a user over at Ask Different, and I'd like to propose that we add oneboxing support to chat for both iOS and Mac App Store listings. Can this be implemented? It won't only be useful on Ask Different, but it could potentially be helpful on both Stack Overflow and Super User.

Comment: Oneboxing in what hole?

Comment: Just realized this is sorta kinda a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116007/138710

Answer (score 3):

It would be really killer to allow community contributed/maintained oneboxes.

This message was in no way inspired by the fact that [GitHub's Commit Hooks](https://github.com/github/github-services) are completely open source and largely community maintained[image: (SARCMARK)]