# Could chat please onebox TED talks?

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

TED is arguably more educational than YouTube, and [chat onebox support for TED talks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136247/147191) would be welcomed.

Comment: What's TED? Never heard of it...

Comment: @Mysticial http://www.ted.com/

Comment: @Mystical. It's a speakers forum: Educational and inspirational talks on various subjects. Here's an example from the geekier side of TED: [Beware online filter bubbles](http://www.ted.com/talks/eli_pariser_beware_online_filter_bubbles.html).

Comment: The Ted I'm planning to watch next is this one: http://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=fvwrel&v=5AJtjJebDes still, +1 for the suggestion, makes sense

Comment: How often are these links used that they need oneboxed? *Where* are they used? Very important information. If no one ever links to the site, then oneboxing support is a waste of time. Any stats?

Comment: @animuson http://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=ted.com

Comment: A whole 47, and 37 more on Stack Overflow Chat? That seems hardly worth any effort, compared to YouTube's 18,000 and Wikipedia's 14,000.

Comment: @Mysticial: An example of a TED talk (somewhat related to Stack Overflow) is [Clay Shirky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clay_Shirky)'s *[How cognitive surplus will change the world](http://www.ted.com/talks/clay_shirky_how_cognitive_surplus_will_change_the_world.html)*. [Direct download URL](http://download.ted.com/talks/ClayShirky_2010S.mp4) (43 MB, 13 min 07 sec).

Comment: Despite the title, the TED talk *[How the Internet will (one day) transform government](http://www.ted.com/talks/clay_shirky_how_the_internet_will_one_day_transform_government.html)*, is even more relevant to Stack Overflow: 05 min 30 secs - 11 min 58 secs: cooperation without coordination, origin & working of Git, how the open-source world works, GitHub, versions control systems. [Direct download URL](http://download.ted.com/talks/ClayShirky_2012G.mp4) (60 MB, 18 min 32 sec).

Comment: [Aren't most TED Talks on Youtube anyway?](http://www.youtube.com/user/TEDtalksDirector)