# Add onebox support for Vimeo

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

As the title says, can support for oneboxing Vimeo links in chat be added?

Here's one to test with:

http://vimeo.com/58200103

Comment: Oh, hey, there's oEmbed stuff, twitter embed stuff, and even a meta property pointing to a screenshot: `<meta property="og:image" content="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/403/831/403831084_640.jpg">`

Comment: Note that it's **Official Policy** that oneboxes shall *never* be interactive - so this would be limited to screenshots, about text, etc., even if it did happen.

Comment: @michaelb958 so how do YouTube oneboxes fit?

Comment: @Andrew I was fairly sure they were just images as links.