# Can we have "onebox" links like chat on the meta sites?

Tags: feature-request, onebox

It'd be nice to have onebox or "magic" links when on meta sites.   If we post a question about another question on the parent site, the onebox preview like on chat would be helpful.

For example, when I paste the URL `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57286/what-links-and-sites-are-handled-specially-in-chat` in this post, it will show up as a hyperlink:

[Which links and sites are handled specially in chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57286/what-links-and-sites-are-handled-specially-in-chat)

I propose that a mechanism be added to Markdown or the editor to onebox questions like this instead:

[image: onebox]

Note that a real onebox is an HTML construct; the above box isn't a demo but a screenshot.  Having the exerpt and information provided by a onebox would make it easier to discuss questions on meta sites.

Comment: I actually don't understand what this feature-request is asking for.

Comment: @jadarnel27: It is asking for a little preview of the referenced question, as in chat, on Meta sites.

Comment: @Jae That is it exactly.

Comment: I can't think of a situation in which this would be helpful. In chat, a little preview/summary might be enough information to make a point. On a meta site, if someone's linking to a main site post, you probably need to see the full question, maybe with all comments and answers, for appropriate context.