# Improved default linking to other questions

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

When linking to other StackOverflow questions -- be it in a comment, question, or answer -- it would be nice to have better default rendering.

Right now, just pasting in the URL results in this:

> Hey, I think you should look at this other question: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050056/...`

Or there's this option:

> Part of your question is answered [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050056/).

Neither one of those gives people any idea what they're clicking on.
It would be nice instead to have something like:

> Hey, I think you should look at this other question:
>   [SO logo]***Scale down (but not up) images using CSS to fit div container in IE9 (max-width: 100% fix)***[checkbox if answered]

There is already a "Linked" sidebar, so clearly there is an intention to call out links as helpful, and the database query that gets the title of the linked question is in place. I merely suggest we move this inline.

Comment: Are you suggesting something like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61538/can-we-have-onebox-links-like-chat-on-the-meta-sites?rq=1)?

Comment: Yes, but a smaller, inline version, and not just in meta. Also, you sort of make my point with your "this" link ;)

Comment: Well, I'd be hesitant to change *anything* about links in comments

Answer (score 2):

You can, of course, do most of that with Markdown.

`![SO](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico) [Title of question](url to question)`

It would look like this:
[image: SO] [Improved default linking to other questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140853/improved-default-linking-to-other-questions)

Not sure if the "answered" indication is needed.

Edit:
As the comments say, you can't post icons in comments, only in questions or answers. The link part works in a comment too though.

Comment: Cool! It would also be nice if that solution worked in comments, and if the markup could be generated automatically.

Comment: Images are not supported in comments.

Comment: Too much effort to post a link in a comment, though.

Comment: Ehm, just as much effort as posting it in an answer, I'd say.

Comment: @nhahtdh how so? Because in a comment you have to type `[]()` yourself instead of using your mouse to highlight text and click a button above the textbox? 6 of one, half dozen of the other, to me...

Comment: @AaronBertrand: If I post link in comment, I copy and paste the link - done. Comment (as in the container) is rubbish, and should be treated as so. For example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140853/improved-default-linking-to-other-questions

Comment: @nhahtdh still don't understand what's rubbish about [placing some context instead of the URL which gets truncated anyway](http://google.com/), or why that's any harder in a comment than in a question.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Just pure laziness. I do put effort in writing a proper answer, though. And comments to clarify/argue must be clear. Posting link to another question don't need such treatment, for me at least.

Comment: @nhahtdh ok, so the problem is not about effort, it's that you value comments less than most people paying attention to this question.