# Twitter oneboxing - not immediately evident where to click

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, onebox, twitter

First, let me state I don't use twitter, so perhaps to an every day twitter user this would have made sense.

The following is a screenshot of a onebox'ed twitter link:

[image: I considered opening a Localisation bug for the misspelling of Pluralization, but I think being hit with a Z would hurt more than an S because a Z (that's a ZED, not a ZEE) has more pointy bits]

Where do I click to see that tweet in context? I checked in the following locations, in the order of:

1. The whole tweet text
2. The avatar
3. The word "Tweeted"
4. The word "codinghorror"
5. After almost completely giving up, the date

[image: Don't even get me started on mixing up the date format by putting the month before the day. Who does that? Seriously? That's the worst way, followed by DD-MM-YYYY. We should all write our dates YYYY-MM-DD, but that's never going to happen.]

Of course the tweet was still shown out of context (because that's really what Twitter is, quotes out of context), but the point is the link to see the original twitter is almost impossible to find and doesn't really make sense to non-tweeters.

<sub>I'm hesitant in classing this is a `bug` because it's more of a usability issue, but it's the most appropriate tag</sub>

Comment: I didn't even realize that was clickable

Comment: @Michael - neither did I. I kinda waved my mouse around in frustration till I saw it turn into a hand cursor.

Comment: I use twitter but I have no idea of what "oneboxing" is. Also, where did you see this? Do you have a link or something?

Comment: @Peter Oneboxing is something that happens on the [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/); see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57286/what-links-and-sites-are-handled-specially-in-chat/57287#57287). There's an example of one [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/163586)

Comment: @Michael - Thanks. Didn't see the "chat" tag on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how it is on twitter.com itself

[image]

Pray tell, where is the link to the tweet itself in there?

Comment: ... well clearly the source is broken then. Actually that's probably the least of things that's broken about twitter...

Comment: This is how we've always done it, because that's how they've always done it.

Comment: @xaade Twitter is the standard for Twitter. Just like Microsoft is the standard for Microsoft, Apple is the standard for Apple, etc.

Comment: @Jeff That's a useless statement. As effective as Llama dung. Why then do we even have more than one OS company?