# One Boxing Not Occurring in Chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, hyperlinks

I just posted a link to a question in a StackExchange chatroom, and the abbreviated text ( `superuser.com/questions/...` ) was distinctly unhelpful.

And actually, that's exactly what I posted:

> ( [How do I find a file by filename in Mac OSX terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/226566/find-filename-in-osx-terminal/226571) )

And it was rendered as:

> ( superuser.com/questions/... )

Is this a limitation of the parser? Is it meant to only act on content that is just the raw link, and not along side some other content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links to SE questions should be "[oneboxed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57286/which-links-and-sites-are-handled-specially-in-chat)", where the link is replaced with a box that actually displays the post:

[image: Oneboxing example]

Did something go wrong with that?

---

**Edit**: After you revised your post, I looked through the transcript; I assume you're talking about [this chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/268958). Like you guessed, oneboxing only occurs on links that are by themselves on the line; you can't add things like parentheses. This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: Yeah, it's been malfunctioning lately.

Comment: oh yeah, I forgot about that feature. The rooms I frequent are pretty light now that you mention it, despite new questions flowing in.

Comment: I retagged this bug because it's not taking place, I'll clean up the question here in a minute too. I posted a link to superuser in apple.se chat, and it resulted in the above format, not oneboxed.

Comment: Can we talk about "bydesign"? This seems... short sighted. There's lots of horizontal room for it to take place at any time it's linked to, beside, or even below, the rest of the text, attached to the original message.

Comment: @VxJasonxV I don't like it either, I brought it up when chat first launched; you might want to post a feature-request about it and see what they say

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if [our API](http://stackapps.com) is down or malfunctioning for any reason.