# Setup starred feed to replace oneboxing link's display text with onebox text content

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox, chat-stars

Right now if you have oneboxable links, if starred, the feed panel will display this, usually, mangled and hard to read link without any indication of content. (So we lose the benefit of oneboxing content in the feed)

http://twitter.com/#%21/olafurw/status/86077101685477379

In this chat post, the I've reformatted the link so it would display in the feed as the first bit of the content, but that loses the oneboxing.

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1164351#1164351

I'm suggesting that oneboxable links *replace the link display text* as the first X characters of the content (since we can already include it), and that oneboxing should look at the link source instead of display text for its effect.

In other words, automatically do what the I did above, but still interpret the link correctly for oneboxing.

The purpose of this is to increase the readability of the feed.

Comment: @Cody they're referring to in chat when you post a link to a recognised site (such as a twitter one) and it is automatically converted in to something "nice". For example, a twitter URL will be converted to show the tweet, including the user icon, date+time, etc, a link to the SO blog will show the title, image and excerpt and so on.

Comment: @DMA57361: Hrm, figures it's related to the one part of SO that I don't participate in. So when did that get the official name of "Oneboxing"? Google is quite unhelpful here.

Comment: @Cody IIRC It's been the accepted term (at least in the small bits of chat I visit) since they were testing and rolling it out, don't know where it comes from and/or who thought it up.

Comment: Oh, apparently it's a [Google/Search engine term](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2006/07/google-onebox-results.html) @Cody, via [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57286/what-links-and-sites-are-handled-specially-in-chat/57287#57287).

Comment: Um, is that right-hand panel, where starred and pinned postings are shown, called "feed panel"?

Comment: @sbi I like to call it starboard.

Comment: Please fix this.. maybe add a thumbnail.