# Chat room image instead of link

Tags: support, chat, images, onebox

How can you post an image in the chat rooms instead of providing its link?

There should be a "How to Format" within the chat rooms as well.

Comment: "There should be a "How to Format" within the chat rooms as well." -- there is. It's called "help".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no difference; if you post a link on a line by itself (it must be by itself, however) it's automatically [oneboxed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57286/which-links-and-sites-are-handled-specially-in-chat). In the case of image links, that means displaying the image instead of the link. If you want to upload an image instead, there's an "upload..." button next to the text field you can use:

[image: Screenshot of the upload button]

As for formatting, there's a [How do I format my messages?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#formatting) section in the [FAQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Caveat: if your image link does _not_ end in an image extension (.png, .jpg, etc.) and you still want it oneboxed, you must prefix it with an exclamation mark.

Comment: What if you want to put like a caption under the image?

Comment: @ChristopherM Just post a separate message?

Comment: Yup. It's chat after all. Not a forum.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, it will automatically detect an image from the url (based on the ending); if it is unclear, just add a leading `!` and it will *try extra hard* to think of it as an image.