# Onebox for Trello Boards

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

There is currently a [onebox for Trello Cards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57286/which-links-and-sites-are-handled-specially-in-chat).  Cards look kind of like this:

[image]

It would be nice if links to Trello *Boards* were oneboxed also, to tell you the board's name, show its icon, and what organization it belonged to.  Maybe something along what's in the Trello header when you're looking at the board.

[image]