# Expand Amazon Smile links in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat

If I copy and paste a regular Amazon link (http://www.amazon.com/) into chat, the system will expand the link and create a preview of the product.

Many people, myself included, shop using [Amazon Smile](https://org.amazon.com/) so that Amazon will donate part of our purchases to charities we select. In order for this to work, one must browse and purchase using a different subdomain (http://smile.amazon.com/).

If I am browsing Amazon Smile (my default) and copy and paste a link into chat, the system treats it like a regular link and not one of the few [domains it recognizes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57286) and can create a preview.

Please update the Amazon preview to work with the "smile" subdomain as well as "www".