# Automatically detect the title of question from link in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, hyperlinks, title, internal-links

We know the SE has a useful feature of automatically showing the title of question when a link of question is written in the body of question.

For example: `https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288002` automatically shows [Automatically detect the title of question from link in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288002)

Now, **how about implementing or introducing this feature in chat?** *This will help in making chat discussions easier, faster and effective!*

---

Note that similar [FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77394/260388) for comments is declined with the reason:

> No, because comments are processed on the fly. This means a page with 12 links would incur 12 additional database queries -- every time the page is loaded.

But here the thing is different- Once message is posted, the title of stored is stored permanently as a part of message (i.e no issue with loading every time)

And anyway, we know [chat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_place) is quite different from [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/260388).

Comment: Well Q&As already [onebox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57286/307988)

Comment: @cai *Note that the link must be the only thing in the chat message, after a possibly replying-to link (`:123456`). In particular, a message containing `@user` won't onebox.* That is a serious restriction.

Comment: Worth to mention that [similar request for comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments) has been declined - though the reason for declining isn't relevant for chat.

Comment: @PatrickHofman The way we avoid that problem in Arqade's main chat (and other rooms) is to post the onebox link, then follow that up with `cc @user`.  Now admittedly this style implies that the link is directed to the entire room, as well as one person in particular.  The alternative that I see pop up is to mention the person in the link text `[@user](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288002)`, although that doesn't solve the actual problem of knowing the title of the question being linked.