# Stackoverflow.blog posts not oneboxing

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, blog, onebox

Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow blog posts are supposed to onebox, as per this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57286/which-links-and-sites-are-handled-specially-in-chat/57287#57287) but it looks like anything with the .blog TLD doesn't onebox anymore. (See [this chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35818292#35818292) for an example).

Can this be fixed so the blog posts onebox again?

Comment: Yeah, looks like the regex we have for matching blog post links no longer does what it's supposed to. I tried out a quick fix, but it doesn't seem to work locally for me, and I'm not sure if that's just a side-effect of the recent blog platform switch or something else. I'll dig in a bit more later, but overall... yes, we're definitely going to fix the one-boxing, but it may take a couple days since we're just about at the weekend here. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: There's a bunch of different things in play here, one is the move of blog platforms, another is a URL change - a third is that the new blog platform doesn't expose the expected API for oneboxing. The first two I was able to get done, the third, however, I am waiting to see if we can do (the new platform is managed by a third party).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a bunch of different issues causing the Stack Overflow blog to no longer one-box, which are all now fixed.

There's still an issue with some of the archived blogs from the network - I am looking for a way to get those done too.